# Returning occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I've got a task where I'm to discover how many times 'A', 'C', 'G' and 'T' occur in a string, and return it in the following format:

```
A:count C:count G:count T:count
```

I'm very new to Java having started learning Java 3 days ago I've come across literature referring to a HashMap being the most viable and efficient means of storing and retrieving this data - As such, I opted in this method.
I've managed to create the conditionals and store the data, however I'm struggling with the presentation of data as mentioned above.

Apologise for some offensive code in advance, what I have so far is:

```
public class DNA {
     static void characterCount(String dna) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        char[] dnaArray = dna.toCharArray();
        charCountMap.put('C', 0);
        charCountMap.put('A', 0);
        charCountMap.put('G', 0);
        charCountMap.put('T', 0);
        for (char q : dnaArray) {

            if (q == 'A' || q == 'C' || q == 'G' || q == 'T') {
                charCountMap.put(q, charCountMap.get(q) + 1);
            } else {
                continue;
            } 
        }
        System.out.println(charCountMap);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        characterCount("ACTGSRSSDSGGGHHTYTCCCFDT");
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any input, advice or signposting to relevant resources for further learning.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Looks fine so far. So the question you have is how to format the output according to your requirements instead of the default `HashMap` String representation? (i.e. seperated by `:` instead of `=` and without the curly brackets?) Does the output have to be in alphabetical order as shown?

Comment: Thank you for the reply - Yeah that would be correct, at present I'm struggling on how to access the data and appropriately structure it for the specified presentation. 
That's correct, it would be required to be in alphabetical order. 
I'll amend my initial question for further clarity, apologies :)

Comment: you can safely remove the `else { continue; }` code since it's not needed. Everything else looks fine to me :)

Comment: You only need to print the data. `System.out.print("A:" + charCountMap.get('A'));` should get you started.

Comment: Note that "signposting to relevant resources" is a request is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Generate output using `String.format`. The `%d` is a placeholder for a `long` primitive value produced from our passed `Long` object via auto-boxing.

```
String.format( 
    "C:%d A:%d G:%d T:%d" , 
    map.get( "C" ) , map.get( "A" ) , map.get( "G" ) , map.get( "T" ) 
)
```

## Details

Streams makes easier work of this.

Here is a modified version of code from [this article](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-count-occurrences-of-each-character).

The split method returns an array of String objects.

We convert those to uppercase. You could omit this step if you know your inputs to already be in uppercase.

We then filter out any strings that are not our desired CAGT.

Lastly, we use a Collector to get a count of each letter, and store the result in a new map.

```
String input = "ACTGSRSSDSGGGHHTYTCCCFDT" ;
Map < String , Long > map =
    Arrays
    .stream( 
        input.split("") 
    )
    .map( String :: toUpperCase )
    .filter( s -> "CAGT".contains( s ) )
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy( 
            s -> s , TreeMap :: new , Collectors.counting()
        )
    )
;
```

Generate output.

```
String output =String.format( "C:%d A:%d G:%d T:%d" , map.get( "C" ) , map.get( "A" ) , map.get( "G" ) , map.get( "T" ) ) ;
System.out.println( output ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3JiMd8).

> C:4 A:1 G:4 T:4

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the required output is by doing this:

```
String output = charCountMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the below code for that formatting instead of `System.out.println(charCountMap);`:

```
 for (Entry<Character, Integer> c : charCountMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print(c.getKey()+ ":" + c.getValue() + " ");
 }
```

So you will get output like this

`A:1 C:4 T:4 G:4`

Use `"LinkedHashMap"` instead of `"HashMap"` if you want to follow the character sequence.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is use an int array and map the character A-T to an index.   The array size is the number of characters from A to T.  The index 0 maps to A and the index 19 maps to T.

```
static void characterCount(String dna) {
  int[] a = new int[20];
  for(char c: dna.toCharArray()){
    int i = c-'A';
    if (i <= 19) a[i]++;
  }
  System.out.printf("A:%d C:%d G:%d T:%d\n", a[0],a[2],a[6],a[19]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You may concide upper and lower case charachter as well and decide wether "a" is same or different to "A".

If the same, you can change your code to

```
char[] dnaArray = dna.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
```

You might also want to make the logic more stable and check, whether the input string is valid

```
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    if (dna == null || dna.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    char[] dnaArray = dna.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
```

Beside this, you could also start cuonting the hole alphabet and use the int value of the corresponding char.

```
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    if (dna == null || dna.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    char[] dnaArray = dna.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (char q : dnaArray) {

        for (int charachter = 'A'; charachter <= 'Z'; ++charachter) {
            if (q == charachter) {
                charCountMap.put(q, charCountMap.getOrDefault(q, 0) + 1);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(charCountMap);
```

Output:

```
{A=1, R=1, C=4, S=4, T=4, D=2, F=1, G=4, H=2, Y=1}
```

**EDIT**

Use a **TreeMap** to sort the map entries

```
TreeMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Output:

```
{A=1, C=4, D=2, F=1, G=4, H=2, R=1, S=4, T=4, Y=1}
```

Comment: The question is solely about how to format the output, this answer does not address that.

Comment: Ah... did not read that and will enhance my answer.